# Ubuntu One shows music folder, but it's empty?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Logged on to UbuntuOne and it shows in my files that the album was download and says I did it two hours ago but there is nothing in the folder.

Looking more closely there is a purchased music file but nothing is in it. I also noticed that the songs are stile in Que and have been for over 20 hours.Sync is enabled and the music folder has sync checked.

---

Looking more closely there is a purchased music file but nothing is in it. I also noticed that the songs are stile in Que and have been for over 20 hours.Sync is enabled and the music folder has sync checked.

Comment: So it is showing the music on the web app, but not in the directory on your computer? Is UbuntuOne syncing other things or nothing at all. Have you enabled syncing for your music directory?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!